# Any built in method to convert an array of primitive types to a List in java

Tags: java, arrays

When trying to compile this code:

```
char[] chars = "abc".toCharArray();
        List<Character> characterList = Arrays.asList(chars);
        Set<Character> characterSet = new HashSet<Character>(new ArrayList<Character>(characterList));
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(17, 54) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.lang.Character
    lower bounds: char[]
```

It is obvious why I am getting it.

Is there any built in method, without any external libs, that take an array of primitives and returns a list of them ? something like:

```
public List<Character> toCharList(char[] array) {
// create arrays list, loop the array and return it.
}
```

**NOTE: I am looking for something that is built it no libs or others like apache commons. So the question is not really duplicate **

Comment: You could use Java 8 and Streams...

Comment: Out of curiosity did you try to see whether you could cast char[] into Character[] before the list conversion?

Comment: @DavidBrossard Yes :P